# Any chance Spring Zuul updated for Spring boot 2.4.x?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

**TLDR**

Any chance of getting spring cloud netflix zuul 1 running on spring boot 2.4?

**Context:**

- We have an app that uses spring zuul 1 and runs on spring boot 2.3.x
- zuul simply "doesn't work" on spring boot 2.4.x, i.e. wasn't updated to run on spring 2.4.x.
- I would have expected to see 'deprecation' or 'end of life' warnings. Maybe I missed them.

[image: Zuul Requires Spring Boot < 2.4.0.M1]
**Why we care**

Spring boot 2.4.x adds nice functionality for building docker images; this functionaltiy doesn't work on spring 2.3.x .

e.g..
*The generated image can be published to a Docker registry by enabling a publish option and configuring authentication for the registry using docker.publishRegistry properties.*

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/

**Question**

- Any chance that zuul 1 maintainers will updat zuul 1 to run on spring 2.4? If so, when?
- Any documentation on "migrating from zuul1 to spring cloud gateway"

We ran into a few 'gotchas' with zuul--so know that switching from zuul to spring cloud gateway might require non-trivial work.

Thanks!

Comment: We have a similar need  . Was trying to understand the spring cloud gateway and it seems its not compatible with spring mvc . Do you have any break through on the way forward .